# x and y axis interchanged in scatter3 plot in GNU Octave

Tags: plot, octave, scatter3d

Suppose I want to plot `f(x,y,z) = x^2` using the `scatter3` function of GNU Octave.
My code is

```
x = [1,2,3,4];
y = [1,2,3,4,5];
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

for xi = 1:4
    for yi = 1:5
        for zi = 1:6
            a(xi,yi,zi) = x(xi) * x(xi);
        endfor
    endfor
endfor

[xx yy zz] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
scatter3(xx(:), yy(:), zz(:), [], a(:),'fill');
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
colormap(rainbow)
colorbar()
```

[image]
I am getting the above plot, which shows that the function changes with `y` (it is actually `y^2`), and is a constant w.r.t. `x`. Am I doing something wrong? Since `a(xi,yi,zi) = x(xi) * x(xi)`, should not I get `a = x^2` instead, due to the index `xi`?

I have labelled the three axes.

I am using Octave 4.2.2 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Ah,  think you may need to swap x,y inputs in mehsgrid

Comment: @AnderBiguri `a(xi,yi,zi) = x(xi) * x(xi)`, so we should rather have `a = x^2` instead of `a = y^2` (which is there in the plot)

Comment: yup, for plotting, you need to swap `meshgrid(y,x,z)`. This is because what MATLAB/Octave uses as row/column and what you name them do not match.

Comment: But, what if x and y do not have same no. of points? I'll update the post

Comment: It does not matter, your plot is not plotting in the "x" axis the variable `x`, its plotting `y`. So you change the meshgrid to fit it to the plot. You can also change which axes you call x and y in the plot if you preffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap `x` and `y` axes in your function matrix.

```
a(yi,xi,zi) = x(xi) * x(xi);
```

This is necessary due to the way `meshgrids` work in scatter plots. In your case, the `x` and `y` axes are flipped to Octave. You need to flip them before you plot to get the expected output.

From the [documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/surf.html):

> The surface mesh is plotted using shaded rectangles. The vertices of the rectangles [x, y] are typically the output of meshgrid. over a 2-D rectangular region in the x-y plane. z determines the height above the plane of each vertex. If only a single z matrix is given, then it is plotted over the meshgrid x = 1:columns (z), y = 1:rows (z). *Thus, columns of z correspond to different x values and rows of z correspond to different y values.*

(Text in italic deliberately highlighted)